# Django - table that can be filtered

Tags: python, django, django-views, filtering

I have been looking for a Django app that allows me to create lists of database models that can be sorted, paged and FILTERED.

[django-tables2](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2) seems to be a popular app that handles paging and sorting, but not filtering.

To clarify: I would like to have a form for filtering the list by certain attributes, like minimal price, maximum price, etc.

There has to be some app out there that does this, right?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We use django-filter. Maybe that is right for you as well? https://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: I was just about to ask if django-filter can work with django-tables2, but Google reveals an answer: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-filter/67Q6fJIw9VE. So apparently it's possible. Thanks!

Comment: django-filters is great ! Please check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611741/django-tables-column-filtering/15129259#15129259 on how you can do filtering with django-tables2 (and how you can use django-filter with django-tales2).