# Handle django-filter form with split fields using django-crispy-forms

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms, django-filter

I have a [django-tables2](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) table that is being filtered with [django-filter](http://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). I have implemented a scheme based on  **option D** from [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15129259/666823).

However, I am using [django-crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) with bootstrap3 for my form rendering. This works great until I want to apply a [RangeFilter](http://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/filters.html#rangefilter), which spits out two fields (a min and max field).

The output I get is [image: Resultant crazy price field]

I would like to control each of those fields manually so that I could PrependedAppendedText them separately.

Any ideas?

***views.py***

```py
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import PrependedAppendedText, FormActions
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Submit, Button
from django_tables2 import SingleTableView
from aids.filters import AidFilter
import os

class FilteredSingleTableView(SingleTableView):
    filter_class = None

    def get_table_data(self):
        self.filter = AidFilter(
            self.request.GET,
            queryset=super(FilteredSingleTableView, self).get_table_data(),
        )
        self.filter.helper = FormHelper()
        self.filter.helper.form_id = 'id_filterForm'
        self.filter.helper.form_class = 'form-inline'
        self.filter.helper.form_method = 'get'
        self.filter.helper.form_tag = True
        self.filter.helper.field_template = os.path.join('bootstrap3', 'layout', 'inline_field.html')

        self.filter.helper.layout = Layout(
            'name',
            PrependedAppendedText('price', '$', 'min', ),
            # Fieldset(
                # 'Filter by price',
                # PrependedAppendedText('price_0', '$', 'min', id='id_price_0'),
                # PrependedAppendedText('price_1', '$', 'max', id='id_price_1'),
            # ),
            'maint',
            'post',
            'supplier',
            FormActions(
                Submit('submit_filter', 'Filter', css_class='btn-primary'),
                Button('clear', 'Clear', css_class='btn-sm')
            )
        )

        return self.filter

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(FilteredSingleTableView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter'] = self.filter
        return context
```

***filters.py***

```py
import django_filters
from aids.models import Aid

class AidFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_type='contains')
    price = django_filters.RangeFilter()

    class Meta:
        model = Aid
        fields = ['name', 'price', 'maint', 'post', 'supplier']
```

***view_table.html***

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock %}

{% block extra_css %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}django_tables2/themes/paleblue/css/screen.css" />
{% endblock %}

{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block heading %}
    {{ title }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% crispy filter.form filter.helper %}
    {% render_table table %}
{% endblock %}
```

***urls.py***

```py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from aids.filters import AidFilter
from aids.models import Aid
from aids.tables import AidTable
from sadb import settings
from aids.views import FilteredSingleTableView

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^aid_form/', 'aids.views.aid_form'),
    url(r'^supplier_form/', 'aids.views.supplier_form'),
    url(r'^view_aids/', 'aids.views.view_aids'),
    url(
        r'^$', FilteredSingleTableView.as_view(
            model=Aid,
            table_class=AidTable,
            template_name='view_table.html',
            filter_class=AidFilter
        ), name='filtered_view'
    ),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem after overriding the `DateRangeFilter` and got around it by amending the widget output to have a div wrapper around it with the `form-inline` class with the amended bit in `def format_output()` at the end of the widget class.

Screenshot at https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwIBq4D09D0RaDZGTWhCWnJaZU0 (reputation won't let me post images yet!)

My full code is below (originally taken from https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-filter/lbi_B4zYq4M/37s63u0WrncJ)

```
class DateRangeWidget(forms.MultiWidget):
    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        attrs_from = {'class': 'date-from'}
        attrs_to = {'class': 'date-to'}

        if attrs:
            attrs_from.update(attrs)
            attrs_to.update(attrs)

        widgets = (forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs_from), forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs_to))
        super(DateRangeWidget, self).__init__(widgets, attrs)

    def decompress(self, value):
        if value:
            return [value.start, value.stop]
        return [None, None]

    def format_output(self, rendered_widgets):
        return '<div class="date-range form-inline">' + ' - '.join(rendered_widgets) + '</div>'


class DateRangeField(forms.MultiValueField):
    widget = DateRangeWidget

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fields = (
            forms.DateField(),
            forms.DateField(),
        )
        super(DateRangeField, self).__init__(fields, *args, **kwargs)

    def compress(self, data_list):
        if data_list:
            return slice(*data_list)
        return None


class DateRangeFilter(Filter):
    field_class = DateRangeField

    def filter(self, qs, value):
        date_start = datetime.datetime.combine(value.start, datetime.time(0, 0, 0))
        date_stop = datetime.datetime.combine(value.stop, datetime.time(23, 59, 59))

        if value:
            lookup = '%s__range' % self.name
            return qs.filter(**{lookup: (date_start, date_stop)})
        return qs
```