# Django - set filter field label or verbose_name

Tags: django, django-filter

I'm displaying a table of data using django-tables2.

For filtering I'm using the solution from here:

[How do I filter tables with Django generic views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25256239/how-do-i-filter-tables-with-django-generic-views)

My problem is only that I can't set the labels for the filter form. This is also imposible to google as words "django, form, filter, label" are quite general :(

My filter class:

```
import django_filters as filters
from models import Sale

class SaleFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Sale
        fields = ['CompanyProductID', 'CompanySellerID', 'CompanyRegisterID']
        labels = {
            'CompanyProductID': 'Article',
            'CompanySellerID': 'Seller',
            'CompanyRegisterID': 'Cash register'
        }     #THIS IS NOT WORKING
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
>     class Meta:
>         model = Product
>         fields = ['manufacturer']
>
>     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
>         super(ProductFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
>         self.filters['manufacturer'].extra.update(
>             {'empty_label': 'All Manufacturers'})
> ```

Comment: what about the label for the form element? is it possible that it cannot be changed?

Comment: what about `some_model_field = tables.Column(verbose_name=u'Some Label')` in your `Table` class?

Comment: Yeah, I have that set and it works in table columns, but not for filter form. For now I just set those labels to "display:none" and I have empty_label set, so it's obvious what the dropdown does.. I guess.

Comment: The link to the docs doesn't work anymore. In the latest documentation I couldn't find this example.

Comment: @cezar it was my example :) I don't remember why posted link here ... removing, thanks

Answer (score 14):

To set custom labels you can do it this way. Not sure if it is a new functionality.

```
import django_filters as filters
from models import Sale

class SaleFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    CompanyProdutID = filters.CharFilter(label='Article')
    CompanySellerID = filters.CharFilter(label='Seller')
    CompanyRegisterID = filters.CharFilter(label='Cash register')

    class Meta:
        model = Sale
        fields = ['CompanyProductID', 'CompanySellerID', 'CompanyRegisterID']
```

Use the filter that you want for each field.

[docs](http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/develop/ref/filters.html#filter-reference)

Note:

for some reason

```
import django_filters as filters
filters.CharField(...)
```

is not working for me. I have to use it like this:

```
from django_filters import CharFilter
CharFilter(...)
```

Comment: Yes, this works. I had no problem with importing - `filters.CharFilter` works as expected.

Comment: There is no `CharField` in `django_filters`! Therefore it can't work.

Answer (score 13):

Previous answer will duplicate the filter fields. Here is how to do it:

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(SaleFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.filters['CompanyProductID'].label="Article"
       self.filters['CompanySellerID'].label="Seller"
       self.filters['CompanyRegisterID'].label="Cash register"
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer !

Answer (score 0):

I actually believe the op was asking about the "Label name". Not the field name. In order to do this simply do something like the following.

```
class Name_of_Filter(django_filters.FilterSet):

#example of how to set custom labels
your_field_name = django_filters.WhateverFilterYouWantHere(label='Whatever you want')

class Meta:
    model = Your_Model_Here
    fields = ['your_field_name'] 
    #could also do something like '__all__' to get all the fields for that table just have to refer to your models to get the field name
```