# Using UpdateView's success_url to return to PagedFilteredTableView

Tags: django

I followed [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25256239/how-do-i-filter-tables-with-django-generic-views) to implement a table with filtered content. In the displayed table, I have a cell in each row that allows a user to click on a link and edit that row's data. In the process, UpdateView is used.

On a submit from UpdateView's form, I'd like to return to the filtered content/table that was used to initiate the connection for editing the row's data.

In my code below, the 'next is {}' prints the desired URL but the framework returns an error:
`The view ...didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`

Which function should I use to have the UpdateView return to the desired URL?

```
class UpdateMyModelView(UpdateView):
    model = MyModel
    template_name='data_form.html'
    fields = ['A', 'B', 'C']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        r = self.request
        p = r.POST
        print ('request is: {}'.format(r))
        print ('p is {}'.format(p))
        print ('request POST.next is: {}'.format(p['next']))
        self.success_url = p['next']
        print ('next is {}'.format(self.success_url))
        super(UpdateMyModelView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view does not have a return statement, so it is returning `None`. If you call `super()`, then you should return the result.

```
return super(UpdateMyModelView, self).form_valid(form)
```

In this case, it looks like it would be better to override `get_success_url` instead of `form_valid`:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return self.request.POST.get('next', '/default-url/')
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Is the idea that the get() is doing a dict lookup for next and using regex of some kind to replace default-url with value of 'next' lookup?

Comment: Using `get()` allows you to specify a fallback if the key is missing. If you do `request.POST['next']` then you'll get a `KeyError` if `next` is missing from the post request.