# Adding work inside UpdateView before template is rendered

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I'm using `UpdateView` as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39539926/using-updateviews-success-url-to-return-to-pagedfilteredtableview). I'd like to extend the class below so that some object specific calculations can be performed before the html page is rendered. For example, some dummy code below, `do_some_calc()` will add two numbers and the result will be stored in the object/instance of MyModel.

Is there a preferred approach?

```
models.py:

class MyModel(models.Model):
    A = models.FloatField(null=True)
    B = models.FloatField(null=True)
    C = models.FloatField(null=True)

    def do_some_calc(self):
        self.C = self.A + self.B
```

#

```
views.py:

class UpdateMyModelView(UpdateView):
    model = MyModel
    template_name='data_form.html'
    fields = ['A', 'B', 'C']

    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.request.POST.get('next', '/default-url/')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is debatable whether get_success_url is the right place to do this. form_valid is probably the better place for it.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.A = instance.B + instance.C
    return super(UpdateMyModelView, self).form_valid(form)
```

This way you are saving the model only once. If you tried to do it in get_success_url, the model instance has already been saved in the form_valid method of the super class.

```
def get_success_url(self):
    # note self.object is the model instance
    self.object.A = self.object.B + self.object.C  
    return self.request.POST.get('next', '/default-url/')
```

Comment: Glad to have helped