# django-tables2: "Invalid block tag: 'query string' "

Tags: django, django-tables2

Am new to django-tables2, and cannot understand why I'm getting this result:

```
"Invalid block tag: 'querystring' "
```

...when attempting to use this template:

```
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% querystring "sort"="" %} 
{% render_table table %}`
```

And this line is included in the settings.py file:

`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += ('django.core.context_processors.request',)`

The table renders fine (in its most very basic state) if the **querystring** line is omitted from the template. But am working towards getting it to filter in addition to sort (which doesn't seem to be well documented), therefore I think it is necessary in order to provide URL parameters for the filter.

I had understood that the inclusion of that line in the settings was all that was necessary for the **querystring** tag in the template to work, but apparently not...?

Comment: Can you post the view that is responsible for rendering the table?

Answer (score 2):

From what I see, you are loading *only* `render_table` from `django_tables2`! If you wanted to also use the `querystring` tag you could instead do a `{% load django_tables2 %}` to load all tags!

As a more general comment, I see that you want to add filtering to the tables. I am not sure why you need that -- please check my answer to this question [Django Tables - Column Filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611741/django-tables-column-filtering) for an extensive analysis of filtering on django-tables2.